# Handling right-click within a MenuItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

Is it possible to check for a right-click on a menu item in .NET?

It appears that the framework doesn't expose it as an Event, but I've seen other applications (like Chrome and Firefox) which allow you to bring up a right-click context menu for a menu item. Presumably with a little event-loop magic you can do the same thing in .NET, right?

**EDIT**: I'm talking about desktop application programming, not ASP.NET.

Comment: the fact he is talking about chrome and firefox, i would say asp.net.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox are simply examples of applications using win32 that allow right-click on menu items. I didn't mean to steer you toward web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an unnatural act.  Menus are designed to automatically pop down when they lose the focus.  The context menu will take the focus, end of menu.  MenuStrip will fight you tooth and nail, I haven't seen it done.

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms I'm unsure, I don't think so, the Click event is a generic `EventHandler`

In WPF, You can, the `OnClick` Event passes in a `System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs` object, which has properties on it like `.MiddleButton` `.RightButton`

For ASP.NET You need to use javascript to catch the right-click and submit a secret form, initiate a post-back, or use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what was asked for but is a decent compromise and isn't too big a stretch from the UI standards viewpoint.
WinForms menus don't seem to even respond to right clicks so use the presence/absence of the shift key being pressed instead.

```
private void MenuClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift) DoSpecialStuff();
    else DoNormalStuff();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `Click` event you can detect right mouse click with:

```
Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Right;
```

Though you might want to check this also in `Closing` event so to prevent `Close` event from being raised.